# How to make relation between MySQL tables

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to make relation between 3 tables in my MySQL database. User can have multiple Brands -> one Brand can have multiple CarModels. One CarModel can't be in more Brands. The Brands and CarModels must be unique. The Brands and CarModels can be added only if user is logged. I used ASP .NET Core UserIdentity.

This is my Brand Model:

```
public class Brand
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string BrandName { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Author")]
    public string AuthorId { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationUser Author { get; set; }
}
```

This is my CarModel

```
 public class CarModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Model { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Brand")]
    public string BrandId { get; set; }
}
```

This is my ApplicationDbContext

```
 public virtual DbSet<Brand> Brands { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<CarModel> CarModels { get; set; }
```

Can someone tell me how to make the relation between the tables? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, create the collection entity, i.e. Brand. Then reference the Id of the ApplicationUser entity within that

Declare both classes with navigation properties to each other. Mark one of the tables (the dependent table) with the `ForeignKey` attribute on its Primary Key. EF infers one-to-many from this:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<Guid, GuidUserLogin, GuidUserRole, GuidUserClaim>
    {
        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(ApplicationUserManager manager)
        {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            return userIdentity;
        }

        public ApplicationUser()
        {
           Brands = new Collection<Brand>();
        }

        public ICollection<Brand> Brands { get; set; }
    }

public class Brand
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string BrandName { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Author")]
    public string AuthorId { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationUser Author { get; set; }

    public virtual List<CarModel> CarsModel { get; set; }
}

 public class CarModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Model { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Brand")]
    public string BrandId { get; set; }
}
}
```